# How to convert workweek to month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have following table:

```
 Workweek  Month
   201730   July
   201728   July
   201731   July August
```

How i convert the workweek to month by using python pandas? Anyone can share be idea? By the way, my Sunday is consider the first day of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Workweek` is a string:

```
import datetime, calendar
df['Month'] = df['Workweek'].apply(lambda x:\
                            calendar.month_name[\
                            datetime.datetime.strptime(x + ' 0', "%Y%W %w").month])
```

Another way to express the same solution without explicitly requiring `datetime`:

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Workweek'] + ' 0', format="%Y%W %w")\
                .dt.month.apply(lambda x:calendar.month_name[x])
```